# Using a C# library in C++/CLI project: compile-time error "undefined class"

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I'm trying out using a C# library from a managed C++ project (CLR) for the first time and am experiencing compile-time problems.

The C# library in question is the **Optional** library from *Nils Lück* (https://github.com/nlkl/Optional).
I created a simple demo project so I can paste the code here for you to see. Basically, I have a C# class that has a public method which returns an

```
Option<string, MyExceptionType>
```

which is a generic type from the **Optional** library. Then I call this method from the C++/CLR project.

First, this are the compile-time error messages I get:

[image]
[image]

And here the code:

**C# class**

```
namespace OptionalAndCpp
{
    using Optional;

    public class MyException
    {
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }

    public class Something
    {
        public Option<string, MyException> DoStuff()
        {
            return Option.Some<string, MyException>("Hello");
        }
    }
}
```

**Wrapper header**

```
#pragma once

class TheWrappingClass
{
public:
   void DoStuffFromWrapper();
};
```

**Wrapper implementation**

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include "TheWrapper.h"

#using <OptionalAndCpp.dll>
#using <Optional.dll>

void TheWrappingClass::DoStuffFromWrapper()
{
   OptionalAndCpp::Something^ sth = gcnew OptionalAndCpp::Something();

   auto result = sth->DoStuff();
}
```

That's all. And when I hit compile, I get the errors shown in the screenshot above.

I took a look at the source code of the library and saw that it relies extensively on generics and extension methods, so it made me wonder whether it's a similar problem as with exporting C++ function templates from a DLL (which you can't), but I'm sincerely clueless.

Is it possible that some C# libraries are not usable from a C++/CLR project at all for some reason? As I already mentioned this is the first time I'm doing this and I have a lot more experience with C# than with C++.

Has anyone ever encountered a similar problem?

I'm grateful for any help and/or insights you may have.

Comment: Hi Adriano, thanks for your reply. I do have #using statements for both the C# assembly `#using <OptionalAndCpp.dll>` and the 3rd party assembly `#using <Optional.dll>`, and I've set up the _"Additional #using directories"_ property for the C++ project. Or did you mean something else?

Comment: I already tried changing the order of the usings, and "add reference" at the project level, but it doesn't change anything.
It seems to me that the problem lies with the Optional library itself. According to the output, the error occurs inside the 3rd party library when it uses its own code (screenshot in the question). My biggest suspicion lies with the extension methods therein.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti your assumption is correct; both projects target the same framework version and mscorlib is referenced in the CLI project :|

Comment: Unless there is something obvious we can't see...it's weeeeird!

Comment: Are both C# libraries AnyCPU?

Comment: @BenVoigt I don't know about the **Optional** library since it's 3rd party, but my entire solution is set to _AnyCPU_